# Why is there a Digg icon at the bottom of pages that don't have any Digg buttons?

Tags: javascript, social-networking, digg

I've added a Digg button to all the items in my site.  The javascript required for dynamic Digg buttons is just before my `</body>` close tag.

```
<body>
    ...
    <script src="http://digg.com/tools/diggthis.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
```

Everything works on pages that have the dynamic Digg buttons on them, but on pages that don't, an orphan Digg icon is floating in space at the bottom of the page.

Is this normal behaviour?  How can I prevent it?

Comment: Nothing but the bog standard script call.  Nowhere else in my code is there any call to the Digg button.

Comment: Might be some drawing code in the diggthis.js. You might want to leave out the script entirely if you don't want the digg button... Or post your code.

Comment: There is no other code.  When I remove the script tag, the icon goes away.  It also doesn't matter where in the code I put it.  Even before </html> and it still renders there.  It would seem it expects at least one Digg button present or it renders its own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I broke down and simply took the `<script>` out of my base template and only put it on pages with digg buttons.  Took some extra template code to make it work, but it gets rid of the "ghost" button.